# ASP.NET Core 6 and EF Core - distributed transaction

Tags: entity-framework-core, transactions, distributed-transactions

We have upgraded recently from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET 6.0 and we encounter several issues. One of them is related to using `System.Transaction` which somehow is being upgraded to distributed transaction for database operations that involve non-clustered database servers.

I searched but I was unable to find when/how a transaction scope is upgraded to distributed transaction?

We are using short lived contexts, so each write operation (we have 6 of them) in the transaction block creates a context and dispose of it when done.